# What is the percentage shown on tag wiki pages?

Tags: support, badge-progress

I just noticed the following.

> 1 tag wiki edits (2% done)

What is that 2 percent?

Comment: Focus out a bit, it's explained two lines above...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your badge progress towards [Research Assistant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/173/research-assistant) badge.

Research Assistant requires 50 tag wikis edit. And here you have edited 1 tag wiki that means 2%.
(100 * 1 / 50)

Comment: I think the `2%` should be `<abbr>`'d to show that information on hover.